# AngularJS How can I display html within an textarea using ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

How can I display html within an textarea using ng-model?
Or how can I disable or undo the sanitized-functionality for my ng model?

I´m able to display the data correct using ng-bind-html-unsafe like in the following example, but than I can´t access the input using $scope.formData[data.name] anymore.

```
<textarea ng-bind-html-unsafe="formData[data.name]"></textarea>
```

When I´m trying this, it does only display the sanitized code and I´m able to access the input using $scope.formData[data.name]:

```
<textarea ng-model="formData[data.name]"></textarea>
```

The input is encoded and looks like:

```
Funktionalit&auml;t  &quot;isHybrid&quot;,  &Uuml;bersicht &quot;Kategorien anzeigen&quot; / &quot;Ki
```

Is there any filter / out of the box angular-way or do I have to create a directive to solve this?

**UPDATE:** I skipped this issue by disabling the encoding on php-side, but maybe there is still a nice solution out there to manually decode the data using angularjs using an html-tag or filter?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if you already fixed your code (I guess so by the time this question were written), but I faced the same issue, and did it this way, with a helper directive that fetches data from the ngModel and updates it as well:

```js
yourApp.controller('HtmlCtrl', function(){
  $scope.items = [{htmlField:'<p>stuff</p>'},{htmlField:'<p>more stuff</p>'}];
});

yourApp.directive('htmlText', function(){
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'require': 'ngModel',
    'link': function(scope,element,attrs,model) {
      model.$formatters.push(function(val){
        return val.htmlField;
      });

      model.$parsers.push(function(val){
        model.$modelValue.htmlField = val;
      });
    } 
  };
});
```

And the HTML looks like

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td><textarea ng-model="item" html-text></textarea></td>
</tr>
```